# Reopen - How should I give notice of my resignation to a boss who has been a fantastic mentor?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-request

[How should I give notice of my resignation to a boss who has been a fantastic mentor?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/88898/2322)

This question was closed as a duplicate of a previous question (which apparently I also answered).

I do not believe it is a duplicate because:

- Having a boss as a mentorfigure is a different situation as the relationship will be different
- the duplicate question is about "what customs should I follow when leaving a company?"

Note that the other proposed duplicates are also about quitting a new job, not somewhere where the OP has been an employee for 3+ years and has a great working relationship with their manager.

Answer (score 5):

This had 4 reopen votes, I just cast the 5th.